# Is it possible to write text and charts into an excel along with dataframes from pandas?

Tags: pandas, charts, heatmap, xlsx, xlsxwriter

I have been able to write write multiple dataframes into each worksheet in a workbook, but I need to be able to add charts and heatmaps alongside them. Is there a way to do that?

I've been using this to write the dataframes into the xlsx:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name= sheet_name_var,startrow=row_count[sheet_name_var])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an [example of adding a dataframe and a chart](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_chart.html) to an Excel file using XlsxWriter and Pandas, from the XlsxWriter docs.

Here is an [example go adding a conditional format based on a dataframe](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_conditional.html). This can be used to simulate a heat map.

See also [Working with Python Pandas and XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html).